# Simple_Form is looking for a path but can't find it undefined method trial_subscriptions_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

Here is my views/trials/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @subscription do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :manual_expiry_date %>
      <%= f.association :user %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
```

I have

```
resources :trials
```

in my trials_controller.rb

```
def new
  @subscription = TrialSubscription.new()
end

def create
  @subscription = TrialSubscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for adding a host!"
    else
      flash["not working yet"]
    end
end
```

Its yelling `undefined method trial_subscriptions_path`

TrialSubscription is a model class that inherits from Subscription model. A user has many subscriptions.

I need to build a form so when a user puts in the email, the user gets created and that its associated trial subscriptions get created as well.

I am iterating through the form. I want the trial_subscription created before working on its (belong_to) association or hooking up the user part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `resources :trials` with `resources :trial_subscriptions`